# Using For Loops to create tabular input in Python from a list

Tags: python, for-loop

My code is the following. There are 3 bus stops in the simulation and 10 iterations of these three stops. I also included the list of board rates and the number of iterations.

```
   def run_sim(iterations, board_rates):
        mylist = []
        numstops = len(board_rates)
        for i in range(iterations):
            stop = i + 1
            mylist.append(stop)
            for j in range(numstops):
                boarding = board_rates[j]
                mylist.append(boarding)
            print('{0:^10d}{1:^10d}'.format(stop, boarding))
        return mylist
```

> In this example, board_rates = [8, 10, 8] and iterations = 10

My output is:

```
1         8     
1         10    
1         8     
2         8     
2         10    
2         8     
3         8     
3         10    
3         8     
4         8     
4         10    
4         8     
5         8     
5         10    
5         8     
6         8     
6         10    
6         8     
7         8     
7         10    
7         8     
8         8     
8         10    
8         8     
9         8     
9         10    
9         8     
10        8     
10        10    
10        8
```

but I want my output to look like:

```
1         8       
2         10     
3         8     
4         8     
5         10     
6         8     
7         8      
8         10     
9         8     
10        8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code:

```
def run_sim(iterations, board_rates):
    mylist = []
    numstops = len(board_rates)
    for i in range(iterations):
        stop = i + 1
        mylist.append(stop)
        for j in range(numstops):
            boarding = board_rates[j]
            mylist.append(boarding)
        print('{0:^10d}{1:^10d}'.format(stop, boarding))
    return mylist

list = [8, 10, 8]
run_sim(10, list)
```

and the ouput was

```
    1         8     
    2         8     
    3         8     
    4         8     
    5         8     
    6         8     
    7         8     
    8         8     
    9         8     
    10        8
```

So maybe you have another error on other parts of the code, but this bit seems to be working as expected!